# Mysterious stack issue with GCC 4.6.2

Tags: gcc, assembly, stack, osdev

I'm working on the Pintos toy operating system at university, but there's a strange bug when using GCC 4.6.2. When I push my system call arguments (just 3 pushl-s in inline assembly), some mysterious data also appears on the stack, and the arguments are in the wrong order. Setting -fno-omit-frame-pointer gets rid of the strange data, but the arguments are still in the wrong order. GCC 4.5 works fine. Any idea what specific option could fix this?

NOTE: the problem still occurs with -O0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was -fomit-frame-pointer, which has been enabled by default since 4.6.2. -fno-omit-frame-pointer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without a code example and a listing of the result from your different compilations, it's difficult to help you. But here are three possible causes for your problems:

1. Make sure you understand how arguments are pushed to the stack. Arguments are pushed from the back. This makes it possible for `printf(char *, ...)` to examine the first item to find out how many more there are. If you want to call the function `int foo(int a, int b, int c)`, you'll need to push *c*, then *b* and finally *a*.
2. Could the strange data on the stack be a return address or EFLAGS? I don't know Pintos and how system calls are made, but make sure that you understand the difference between CALL/RET and INT/IRET. INT pushes the flags onto the stack.
3. If your inline assembly has side effects, you might want to write `volatile`/`__volatile__` in front of it. Otherwise GCC is allowed to move it when optimizing.

I need to see your code to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Parameters are passed with three pushl-s followed by a push of the system call number (in asm volatile). However, when the kernel segment sees the memory the arguments are 3 1 2 order (or even garbage, depending on the options). With GCC 4.5 they're in the right place, and in the right order.

Comment: @vahokif Could you show a code example? I don't know if I can solve it, but it's almost impossible without even looking at the code. Of course, there are sometimes bugs in compilers. In that case you might want to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clean the parameters on stack after the syscall? gcc may not be aware that you touch the stack and generate code depends on the stack pointer it expected.
-fno-omit-frame-pointer force gcc to use e/rbp for accessing locate data but it just hide the actual problem.